# Gate cancellations in Hamiltonian simulation

Tags: hamiltonian-simulation, quantum-control

I'm a bit confused about in which case the two unitary gates in a quantum circuit could be canceled? I'm reading an example in [this paper](https://quantum-journal.org/papers/q-2020-09-12-322/pdf/). In the following diagram, Figure (b) is a simplified circuit of Figure (a):
[image]
I'm wondering if Figure (b) is the simplest optimization result of Fig. a? In their diagram, the first and third part of the circuit are grouped together, I do understand that two Hadamard gates are canceled, but why the two C-NOT gates (acting on the second and the ancilla qubit) are also canceled? (in this case, those two C-NOT gates are not next to each other)

My guess is they're canceled since no unitary gates are directly sandwiched between the two control qubits (despite there's another C-NOT between them targeted at the same ancilla qubit). Is this the right explanation? How can I have a better understanding of what's going on?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is true that these two circuits are equivalent:

[image]

as the the controlled qubit $q_1$ is the same. So if $q_1$ is a $|1\rangle$ then you can see that it will apply two $X$ gates to $q_2$ and they will cancel each other out.

Comment: Thanks, that really helps :)